# Call QtDBus method with array-of-strings arguments

Tags: qt, dbus

I try to call a method with arguments.
For example, list services.

This code

```
#include <QtDBus>
#include <QDebug>

QDBusMessage callDbusMethod(QString method, QList<QVariant> args= {}) {
    QDBusMessage msg;
    if(QDBusConnection::systemBus().isConnected()) {
        QDBusInterface iface("org.freedesktop.systemd1", "/org/freedesktop/systemd1",
            "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
        if(iface.isValid())
            msg= args.isEmpty() ? iface.call(QDBus::AutoDetect, method.toLatin1())
                : iface.callWithArgumentList(QDBus::AutoDetect, method.toLatin1(), args);
        if(msg.type() == QDBusMessage::ErrorMessage)
            qDebug() << msg.errorMessage(); }
    return msg;
}

typedef struct {
    QString path, state; } UnitFile;

int main() {
    QDBusMessage msg= callDbusMethod("ListUnitFilesByPatterns",
        QList<QVariant>{ QVariant(""), QVariant("*.service") });
    //QDBusMessage msg= callDbusMethod("ListUnitFiles");
    if(msg.arguments().size()) {
        const QDBusArgument argUnitFiles= msg.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
        argUnitFiles.beginArray();
        while(!argUnitFiles.atEnd()) {
            UnitFile unit;
            argUnitFiles.beginStructure();
            argUnitFiles >> unit.path >> unit.state;
            argUnitFiles.endStructure();
            qDebug() << unit.path; }
        argUnitFiles.endArray(); }
}
```

Return

"Invalid arguments 'ss' to call org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.ListUnitFilesByPatterns(), expecting 'asas'."

And how to call the method correctly.

Comment: for systemd >= 230

Comment: With QDBusMessage msg= callDbusMethod("ListUnitFilesByPatterns", QList<QVariant>{ QStringList{}, QStringList{"*.service"}}); it's little better

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question in the comments. But I figured I'd explain more here.

In the submission you are passing the argument list of `ss` since your QList has two QVariants which are strings. The signature of org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.ListUnitFilesByPatterns is `asas` or two array of strings. According to [qt's dbus typesystem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdbustypesystem.html), `as` is automatically de-marshaled into a QStringList. Therefore you'd want a QList of QVariants which are QStringLists.

So..

```
QList<QVariant> args = { QVariant(""), QVariant("*.service") };
```

should be

```
QList<QVariant> args = { QStringList() << "", QStringList() << "*.service" };
```